# TF suddenly shifts

Tags: rviz, hector-slam, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I'm trying to make a map with hector and my problem is about TF because although I use 2D pose estimate, after a short time the axes will move suddenly. My launch file has this part inside:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_to_odom" args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0 0 0.0 /odom /base_link 10"/>
<param name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" value="scanmatcher_frame"/>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_frame_laser" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /neato_laser 10"/>
```

The node that I use is given by

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher x y z yaw pitch roll frame_id child_frame_id period_in_ms
```

Where am I doing wrong? Also if I rotate my LIDAR a bit faster, the TF can not follow the movement, so what parameter I have to change in launch file? Thank you all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228275/tf-suddenly-shifts/) by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2016-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're running some other nodes. And that parameter is used by some scan matcher in hector? Then it's likely that the scanmatcher is attempting to improve your localization based on matched scans and updating your map to odom frame.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0